# Realtime conversion of MP3 to PCM using minimp3 produces noise/gaps at beginning of frame

Tags: c++, mp3, pcm, unreal-engine5

I'm using minimp3 (https://github.com/lieff/minimp3) to implement an audio pipeline where I stream MP3 data to an Unreal Engine 5 client using Web Sockets. Once received, I add the data to a TArray (acting as a buffer), and then decode as much as I can to PCM. Once decoded I add the new samples to an audio source. I then repeat this with all MP3 frames in the data stream.

I've confirmed that the MP3 is being transmitted correctly, however, the converted PCM has gaps/noise at the beginning of chunks of MP3 frames that distort the audio during playback.

Attached Code:

https://gist.github.com/DeveloperHarris/c3bd30d6cc689f22ec9e8fc839c80655

The top audio in Audacity is a test MP3 comprised of a 100Hz sine wave received by the Unreal Engine client.
The bottom track is the converted PCM stream.

The noise/gaps seem to occur at the beginning of new chunks. My initial theory was that it's due to the byte reservoir system of MP3 (given that the gap is roughly 3 frames long every time), but I thought minimp3 is supposed to account for that? It's the same instance of mp3d between chunks.

What do I need to do to fix the decoding issues at the beginning of the chunks?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, I needed to read the library docs more carefully:

`The decoder will analyze the input buffer to properly sync with the MP3 stream, and will skip ID3 data, as well as any data which is not valid. Short buffers may cause false sync and can produce 'squealing' artefacts. The bigger the size of the input buffer, the more reliable the sync procedure. We recommend having as many as 10 consecutive MP3 frames (~16KB) in the input buffer at a time.`

Adding a check at the beginning of my decode function that checks if it has 10 consecutive frames was enough to fix the issue.